# parsing faulting module timestamp

Tags: windows, crash

Does anyone know how to parse the timestamp from a windows crash event? For example, how do I convert 0x55f7fcbe to a human readable time stamp?

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.4763.1000, time stamp: 0x55f7fcbe
Faulting module name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.4763.1000, time stamp: 0x55f7fcbe
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000010a2a4
Faulting process id: 0x26a0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d12e98fb593cfc
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE
Report Id: 1cecf154-9a91-11e5-93ee-3417eba4258b
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a Unix style time_t timestamp. 
Check it out on:
http://www.epochconverter.com/

The date you posted is

```
GMT: Tue, 15 Sep 2015 11:10:54 GMT
```

You can find some details about the format on this post [Analyzing a crash in Windows: what does the error message tell us?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319234/analysing-a-crash-in-windows-what-does-the-error-message-tell-us)

Comment: Thanks but the funny thing is that I know the crash happened on Dec 4, 2015... not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: The faulting application start time looks correct though.  0x01d12e98fb593cfc is translated to 2015-12-04 12:37:55 GMT.

Comment: I may have erroneously grabbed the excel.exe time stamp, dbl check with the url above

Comment: Oh ya, that's it. The date you posted is the excel.exe time stamp :)

Comment: Oh I see.  So 0x55f7fcbe is the timestamp for the Excel.exe program and has nothing to do with the crash itself.

Comment: That is correct although if you look on the event log you may find the crash time

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info. The following c# code converts Faulting application start time to a date time:

```
Int64 time = Int64.Parse(args[0], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
time = time / 10000;

DateTime dt = new DateTime(1600, 1, 1);
dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(time);
Console.WriteLine($"{args[0]} converted to universal time is 
{dt.ToString("s")}");
dt = dt.ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine($"{args[0]} converted to local time is 
{dt.ToString("s")}");
```