# Debug Crash in DLL

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

Trying to debug a crash in one of our DLL's.  It is loaded into Server Manager and crashes when trying to configure Active Directory Certificate Services (the DLL is a registered provider).  I know the crash is an access violation and I have the pdb file, just don't know how to go about debugging this.  I've read pages such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319234/analyzing-a-crash-in-windows-what-does-the-error-message-tell-us) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528776/windows-c-is-it-possible-to-find-the-line-of-code-where-exception-was-thrown) (didn't help).  I tried to glean the info using windbg (using lm to get the loaded address, which appears to be 8000000:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe" -z myKSP.dll
```

Then

```
0:000> lm 
start             end                 module name
00000001`80000000 00000001`8005e000 ...
```

Then, since the Event Viewer tells me:

```
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000002a601
```

I tried to view that:

```
0:000> ln 80000000+2a601
Browse module
Set bu breakpoint
```

Nothing is shown.

I have VS2015, so, I tried to attach to the serververmanager.exe process.  Next, I tried loading symbols via Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols and specifying the path, but, when I set a breakpoint, I always receive "no symbols have been loaded".  In the previous symbol windows, I set the cache folder, which downloaded a bunch of stuff, but that did not seem to load anything.

Clearly, I'm not using the tools correctly.  How do I debug a DLL, compiled in Release mode, PDB is available, that is loaded by the ServerManager.exe or whatever sub-process it might spawn)?

Comment: Attach Visual Studio and configure it to break, when a Win32 exception is thrown. You can deal with symbols later, once the debugger has suspended the process.

Comment: Ok, the process has suspended... what should I do now?  Still does not load symbols, I don't seem to have a "modules" window and the stack trace that's shown, is nowhere near my dll.

Comment: You can ask Windows to create a crash dump file for your executable, run it until it crashes then open the file with windbg.exe

Comment: Okay, I have a crashdump file.  I have the PDB that matches the DLL which crashed but, when I open the dump in VS2015, it never seems to load any symbols.  When I click on the callstack entry I wish to view, the Disassembly  just has a line above the assembler which says "No source file".  The modules window also says, for Symbol Status, No symbols.  In the Options->Debugging->Symbols, I have the location where my symbol file is located, it's checked and "All modules" is selected.  Why then, am I not seeing the symbols loaded for this dll?

Comment: You didn't get the whole base address. It's 00000001`80000000, not 80000000.

Answer (score 0):

Start windbg, press Ctrl-D to open your dump file, then type the following. That should give you either a significant stack after one of the kp500, or at least will tell you whether the pdb file doesn't match the binary.

```
.symfix
.sympath+ <FOLDER_WITH_YOUR_PDB>
.reload
!sym noisy
.reload /v /f myKSP.dll
!sym quiet
kp500
.ecxr
kp500
```